# Hive query not working from node.js code

Tags: node.js, npm, hive, hiveql

I have used thrift-hive module for connecting my node.js application to hive server. When I tried to run my node.js web application, my hive queries are not running and it is not giving any error.

```
var express = require('express');
var cmd=require('node-cmd');

var assert     = require('assert');
var thrift     = require('thrift');
var hive  = require('thrift-hive');
//var hive = require('thrift-hive');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log("ruchit1");

var client = hive.createClient({
  version: '0.7.1-cdh3u2',
  server: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 10000,
  timeout: 1000
});
// Execute call 
client.execute('use default', function(err){
  // Query call 
    console.log("ruchit2");


  client.query('show tables')
  .on('row', function(database){

    console.log(database+"ruchit3");
  })
  .on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    client.end();
  })
  .on('end', function(){
    client.end();
  });
});
});

module.exports = router;
```